# Best Blu-Ray Burner and Reader

Tags: blu-ray

I was hoping someone could recommend a great blu-ray burner and player.

- My first requirement is that it can burn M-Disc 100 gig blu-ray
  discs.  I have tons of business documents, home photos and home videos.  The business documents don't take up that much space but the home videos is what takes up a lot.  I have a camcorder and I end up recording about 500 gigs of home videos per year.  Right now, they are saved on a hard drive but I don't want my precious memories to get lost.  I want to be able to see them 30 years from now.
- The second requirement is that it can play Ultra HD 4k movies.  This is not a really a must-have.  There aren't that many 4k movies out anyway.  I think only a few 4k movies were even available last year.  In a couple of years, 4k movies might become more commonplace though so it might be nice to have.

Can anyone recommend the best blu-ray burner/player right now?